# Java primitive data fields in object wrappers

Tags: java, class, integer, wrapper, primitive

I was looking through the documentation for primitive wrappers in Java.

While I understand the utility of all the extra functionality provided by the methods, I don't seem to understand how the object stores the primitive in the first place. There doesn't seem to be any primitive final int.

EDIT: I learnt that Java documentation only shows public fields and methods, and after going through source code see a private int field. 
Just to confirm, it's then as simple as the compiler doing autoboxing/autounboxing through the public constructor to set the value ?

Comment: really, Java1.7 `private final int value;`

Comment: @ScaryWombat , that field is not mentioned in the documentation I have linked above. the answer below has answered my question though.

Comment: If you have something `private` then do you advertise it to the world?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, That makes total sense. I'm not able to  ( and still can't apart from the answer below ) , find any source that says private fields and methods are not shown.

Comment: It is up to the developer to decide what javadocs are written - learn about the `tags` used

Comment: "If you have something private then do you advertise it to the world?" Some people do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the source code of `java.lang.Integer` you will find

```
 private final int value;
```

The reason that you don't see it in the API documentation, is that private attributes and methods are not included in the documentation.